# Shortcode SMS Campaigns - Python

Tags: python, sms, shortcode

I have built a app that handles incoming sms for a short number. We might have several campaigns running at the same time, each with different mechanics and keywords etc.

At the moment I am using Django to handle this.

My biggest concern atm is that the consumer who is using out service is a very low LSM market in South Africa. The sms's come ins weird ways and I get allot of wrong entries.

Im trying to rethink the way to interpret the sms and would like some ideas.

At the moment it basically works like this:

Get the SMS, I split it by a ' or * THEN look first for the KEYWORD. All campaigns have Keywords and I run through a list of live campaign keywords to see if there is a match in the message. Then I go on in the split message and compare or find more words if needed. I need to reply based on the message, like the KEYWORD is there, but not the 2nd or 3rd or what ever parameter.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question, as it currently stands, is too broad and vague to answer. It would help if you included some code to show what you have tried, as well as some samples of good and bad messages, it'll make it much easier for us to help you. Perhaps you could also take a look at http://whathaveyoutried.com for a great article on how to ask good questions?

Comment: I agree that this question is unclear what you mean by 'interpret the sms'. The strict way of running a Keyword SMS service is to ignore any badly formatted entries that don't match a known Keyword. However, your question isn't clear what are the 'weird ways' like Martijn says. Please provide more detail if you still want this question answered

Answer (score 0):

Megan from Twilio here.

You may or may not be using a Twilio [shortcode](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/short-codes/how-can-i-apply-to-migrate-my-live-short-code-to-twilio). But I think your question relates to a little guide we have on [How to Build a SMS Keyword Response Application](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-do-i-build-a-sms-keyword-response-application).

The example there is in PHP but you can get started in [Python here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install) and your code might look like:

```
def sms():
  r = twiml.Response()
  body = request.form['Body']

  if KEYWORD in body: 
  //do some action
```